# External links to location on leafletjs-map

Tags: php, jquery, leaflet

I'm trying to get external links to navigate to given coordinates on a leafletjs-map.

I tried the approach described here: [Leaflet zoom on locations using multiple links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076312/leaflet-zoom-on-locations-using-multiple-links)

This works when I have the links in the same file as the map-div.
But I need to create links in an external file that i include in a div which gets automatically reloaded every 30 seconds.

I've pasted all my files in this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qLHhNv3eDXxFR0pT1cds

In `index.php`I have the following code to autorefresh content from `chkIncludes.php`in a `#results`-div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('chkIncludes.php'); //#results-div is located in main.php
}, 30000); // the "30000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Then I include `main.php`in the body of `index.php`.

In `main.php`I have the `#results`-div that gets autoloaded with content from `chkIncludes.php`.

`chkIncludes.php` is just a php file where I include a lot of ping-scripts.

I want to make the output of each ping-script into a link pointing to the location on the map.

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: This plugin [Leaflet.hash](https://github.com/mlevans/leaflet-hash) allows you to reference specific location by urls+hash.